# Create materialized view based on aggregate materialized view

Tags: clickhouse

The base table

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_sessions
(
    session_id   UInt64,
    session_name String,
    created_at   DateTime
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(created_at)
ORDER BY (session_id);
```

With the following data

```sql
INSERT INTO test_sessions (session_id, session_name, created_at) VALUES
(1, 'start', '2021-01-31 00:00:00'),
(1, 'stop', '2021-01-31 01:00:00'),
(2, 'start', '2021-01-31 01:00:00')
;
```

Created 2 materialized views to get closed sessions

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS test_session_aggregate_states
(
    session_id UInt64,
    started_at AggregateFunction(minIf, DateTime, UInt8),
    stopped_at AggregateFunction(maxIf, DateTime, UInt8)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PARTITION BY tuple()
ORDER BY (session_id)
POPULATE AS
SELECT session_id,
       minIfState(created_at, session_name = 'start') AS started_at,
       maxIfState(created_at, session_name = 'stop')  AS stopped_at
FROM test_sessions
GROUP BY session_id;

CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS test_session_completed
(
    session_id UInt64,
    started_at DateTime,
    stopped_at DateTime
)
AS
SELECT session_id,
       minIfMerge(started_at) AS started_at,
       maxIfMerge(stopped_at) AS stopped_at
FROM test_session_aggregate_states
GROUP BY session_id
HAVING (started_at != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AND
       (stopped_at != '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
;
```

It works normally: return 1 row with existing "start" and "stop"

```sql
SELECT * FROM test_session_completed;
-- 1,2021-01-31 00:00:00,2021-01-31 01:00:00
```

Trying to create a materialized view based on `test_session_completed` with joins to other tables (there are no joins in the example)

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS test_mv
(
    session_id UInt64
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY tuple()
ORDER BY (session_id)
POPULATE AS
SELECT session_id
FROM test_session_completed
;
```

Writing a test queries to test the `test_mv`

```sql
INSERT INTO test_sessions (session_id, session_name, created_at) VALUES
(3, 'start', '2021-01-31 02:00:00'),
(3, 'stop', '2021-01-31 03:00:00');

SELECT * FROM test_session_completed;
-- SUCCESS
-- 3,2021-01-31 02:00:00,2021-01-31 03:00:00
-- 1,2021-01-31 00:00:00,2021-01-31 01:00:00

SELECT * FROM test_mv;
-- FAILURE
-- 1
-- EXPECTED RESULT
-- 3
-- 1
```

**How to fill `test_mv` based on `test_session_completed` ?**

ClickHouse version: `20.11.4.13`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Impossible to create MV over view.
2. MV is an insert trigger and it's impossible to get state `completed` without having state `started` in the same table. If you don't need to check that `started` happen before `completed` then you can make simpler MV and just check `where  completed`.
3. You don't need `minIfState` you can use `min` (SimpleAggregateFunction). It will reduce stored data and will improve performance.
4. I think the second MV is excessive.

Check this:
https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

https://youtu.be/ckChUkC3Pns?list=PLO3lfQbpDVI-hyw4MyqxEk3rDHw95SzxJ&t=9371

---

I would do this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_sessions
(
    session_id   UInt64,
    session_name String,
    created_at   DateTime
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(created_at)
ORDER BY (session_id);


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS test_session_aggregate_states
(
    session_id UInt64,
    started_at SimpleAggregateFunction(min, DateTime),
    stopped_at SimpleAggregateFunction(max, DateTime)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PARTITION BY tuple()
ORDER BY (session_id)
POPULATE AS
SELECT session_id,
       minIf(created_at, session_name = 'start') AS started_at,
       maxIf(created_at, session_name = 'stop')  AS stopped_at
FROM test_sessions
GROUP BY session_id;

INSERT INTO test_sessions (session_id, session_name, created_at) VALUES
(3, 'start', '2021-01-31 02:00:00'),
(3, 'stop', '2021-01-31 03:00:00');


completed sessions:

SELECT session_id,
       min(started_at) AS started_at,
       max(stopped_at) AS stopped_at
FROM test_session_aggregate_states
GROUP BY session_id
HAVING (started_at != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AND
       (stopped_at != '0000-00-00 00:00:00');

┌─session_id─┬──────────started_at─┬──────────stopped_at─┐
│          1 │ 2021-01-31 00:00:00 │ 2021-01-31 01:00:00 │
└────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

And using argMaxState you can aggregate multiple `start` `stop` within one session_id